# Is there any way to disable long press on YouTube Iframe?

Tags: flutter, youtube-api, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to disable long press on YouTube IFrame.
I have used `YouTube_player_iframe` pub and unable to do that.

pub url -> https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe